# JavaFX - ScrollPane in Dialog alternating height

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

i have a problem with JavaFX.
I want to put a ScrollPane in a Dialog and give the Scrollpane a max-height, no min-height or pref-height because it can be shorter.
Here is a simple example to demonstrate my problem.
The Main class:

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application
{
  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage)
  {
    try
    {
      StackPane root = new StackPane();
      MyDialog dialog = new MyDialog();
      Button button = new Button("Test");
      button.setOnMousePressed(e -> dialog.showAndWait());
      root.getChildren()
          .add(button);
      Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
      primaryStage.setScene(scene);
      primaryStage.show();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    launch(args);
  }
}
```

The dialog class:

```
package application;

import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonBar.ButtonData;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.scene.control.Dialog;
import javafx.scene.control.DialogPane;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;

public class MyDialog extends Dialog<ButtonType>
{
  public MyDialog()
  {
    super();
    DialogPane dialogPane = new DialogPane();
    VBox outer = new VBox();
    Button button = new Button("Test");
    setResult(new ButtonType("NO", ButtonData.LEFT));
    button.setOnMousePressed(e -> close());
    VBox inner = new VBox();
    inner.getChildren()
        .add(new Text("Test 1"));
    inner.getChildren()
        .add(new Text("Test 2"));
    inner.getChildren()
        .add(new Text("Test 3"));
    inner.getChildren()
        .add(new Text("Test 4"));
    inner.getChildren()
        .add(new Text("Test 5"));
    ScrollPane scroll = new ScrollPane(inner);
    scroll.setMaxHeight(80);
    outer.getChildren()
        .addAll(button, scroll);
    dialogPane.setContent(outer);
    this.setDialogPane(dialogPane);
  }
}
```

The concrete Problem is following.
The dialog should look like this:
[image]

But everey second time i open it, it looks like this:
[image]

I can't figure out what's the problem. Hopefully anybody can tell me why this is not working.

Comment: Hello, i have found a not so beautiful solution for this problem. I override the computeMinHeight(double width) method of the ScrollPane and return there the height of the content (or the maximum height of the ScrollPane). But i guess there is maybe a more beautiful solution.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce the behaviour with the code provided. For me it always looks like this:

[image]

However is there a specifc reason that you do not want to use a javafx [ListView](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ListView.html) which seems to be doing exactly what you are trying to do?

```
    public MyDialog() {
    super();
    DialogPane dialogPane = new DialogPane();
    VBox outer = new VBox();
    Button button = new Button("Test");
    setResult(new ButtonType("NO", ButtonData.LEFT));
    button.setOnMousePressed(e -> close());
    ListView<Text> inner = new ListView<Text>();
    inner.getItems().add(new Text("Test 1"));
    inner.getItems().add(new Text("Test 2"));
    inner.getItems().add(new Text("Test 3"));
    inner.getItems().add(new Text("Test 4"));
    inner.getItems().add(new Text("Test 5"));
    inner.getItems().add(new Text("Test 6"));
    inner.getItems().add(new Text("Test 7"));
    inner.setMaxHeight(80);
    outer.getChildren().addAll(button, inner);
    dialogPane.setContent(outer);
    this.setDialogPane(dialogPane);
}
```

Comment: Hello, yes you are right, i could also use a ListView, but also with your Code i have the same problem. I'm developing in Eclipse neon under Ubuntu 12.04 LTS using JDK 1.8.0_112. Maybe one of this things causes the problem.

Comment: Its not the JDK that i can tell you, as I use the same. As for Eclipse, I am on Luna but I doubt that to be the isuse. It has likely to do with Ubuntu, maybe it handles its windows differently. You may want to reform your question and post it in a different category, I dont think its a code problem.